# Scrapy - getting HTML without outer tag

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm scraping a page, using **Scrapy**.
I want the **HTML** contents of the TD with "text" class:

```
<tr valign="top">
  <td class="text" width="100%">
    <b>A bunch of HTML</b>

    <ul type="disc">
      <li>Some random text</li>
    </ul>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This is my Scrapy line:

```
for body in response.css('td.text'):
  yield {'body': body.extract()}
```

Which works - except it includes the surrounding td:

```
[
  {"body": "<td class="text" width="100%"> <b>A bunch of HTML</b> <ul type="disc"> <li>Some random text</li> </ul> </td>"}
]
```

This is what I want:

```
[
  {"body": "<b>A bunch of HTML</b> <ul type="disc"> <li>Some random text</li> </ul>"}
]
```

Halp? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this selector:

```
response.css('td.text *')
```

The `*` will select all inner tags.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution, although I still think there must be a smarter way:

```
    bodies = ''
    for body in response.xpath("//td[@class='text']/child::node()"):
        bodies += body.extract()
    yield {'body': bodies}
```